# "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine" when getting new TOR circuit

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tor

I have a .NET application that was using TOR successfully on TOR. After updating the TOR to the version 6.5.2. I am not being able to refresh my TOR IP. Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
Socket server = null;
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9151);
            server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            server.Connect(ip);
            // Please be sure that you have executed the part with the creation of an authentication hash, described in my article!
            server.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("AUTHENTICATE \"password\"" + Environment.NewLine));
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int receivedDataLength = server.Receive(data);
            string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedDataLength);
            server.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("SIGNAL NEWNYM" + Environment.NewLine));
            data = new byte[1024];
            receivedDataLength = server.Receive(data);
            stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedDataLength);
            if (!stringData.Contains("250"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to signal new user to server.");
                server.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                server.Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            server.Close();
        }
```

When it gets to the line

```
receivedDataLength = server.Receive(data);
```

The application breaks with the message System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine'

Someone has any idea of what is going on? Or any tips for finding what is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to `telnet 127.0.0.1 9151` and then `AUTHENTICATE "password"` and `SIGNAL NEWNYM` without error or does it also disconnect?  If authentication fails, you will be disconnected immediately after receiving a `515 Bad Authentication` error.  Possibly the HashedControlPassword got wiped out during the upgrade and your password no longer works.

Comment: I can telnet 127.0.0.1 9151 but then it freezes there. I cant write anything else

Comment: Did it say connecting and then the screen go blank after?  That's weird behavior for telnet.  Does `netstat -ano` show Tor listening on port 9150 and 9151?

Comment: Uau man!! All solved! Thanks a lot! Happens that:
1) My telnet wasnt showing what I was typing...
2) Tor changed the torrc-defaults location from ...\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor to ...\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor

Comment: Glad that helped :) you should add the same 250 check after auth that you have after the signal. Might have given more clues ;)